# Speed up Curl Multi Request

Tags: php, curl

I'm running the following curl multi request, it works fine however I have to run this against 4,000+ queries which, despite using asynchronous calls still takes a while to complete (6+ minutes!) I've looked into various options to speed this up and have added some curl_seopts recommended elsewhere on stackoverflow that apparently help with speed but I've not noticed any real difference.

I'm sure that I may have missed a trick to optimise the speed, does anyone have any tips to make this even faster?

```
function multiRequest($data, $accesstoken, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle

foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] =  $d;
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken;

    $url = 'xxxyyyzzz.json';
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {

    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);
  return $result;
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: The regular libcurl multi interface that this is using isn't really optimal for doing more than say a few hundred parallel transfers. Then the select() oriented approach is really starting to cost. libcurl offers a solution for that in its native API but that is not exposed in PHP... Not to mention how this solution will always suffer from the last N transfers that will stall and take a very long time.

Comment: Hi Daniel, many thanks for your advice, can you elaborate on what you mean by "then the select() oriented approach is really starting to cost."?

Comment: select() gets exponentially slower the more parallelism you're throwing at it. See also [poll vs select vs event-based](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html)

Comment: Hi Daniel, please forgive me for not understanding this but I don't think I am using select() anywhere in my code?

Comment: You are effectively, since the API you're using as provided by PHP does.

Comment: Ok thanks, so in short are you suggesting that I use an API outside of PHP to do this more effectively? If so do you have any recommendations?

Comment: That's another question or for another forum.

Comment: curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip'); replace gzip with just an empty string, this will make curl tell to the server all the encodings curl support, then the server will choose the best encoding they both support. as it currently stands, if your server support deflate but not gzip, it will transfer plain :p